# storage time in segment tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree, rmq

I want to know how many nodes are there in a segment tree made for solving range minimum query problem.

Also, how much time does the build operation take and why?

Comment: Which RMQ algorithm are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

if u use segment tree, build is O(nlgn), each query is O(lgn)

if the array is static, u can also try another algorithm [RMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query). build time is O(nlgn) and each query is only O(1).

Comment: why is build time O(nlogn)? According to me, there are 2n-1 nodes in total. take as an e.g. n=16. so node 1 is 1-16, node 2 is 1-8, node 3 is 9-16..as we keep on dividing, we see that there are 2n-1 nodes. and for each node , there is only one comparison done.. so the time is O(2n-1) or O(n). plz explain me how the time is O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

**Segment Tree Complexity:**

1. Initialization one by one elements: O(NLogN)
2. Initialization from array: O(N)
3. Query range: O(logN)
4. Insert(Update) element: O(logN)